# Flattening a nested map

Tags: performance, recursion, clojure

We're migrating our streaming ETL application from Python into Clojure,
the hottest part of the code isn't yet performing as well as our existing
implementation.  This looks to be down to the algorithmic complexity of our flattening function.

Take a nested map, flatten the data structure and rename keys.  We take data
from multiple sources and have to smudge the data to fit a legacy format.
For this all of the keys/values need to be at the root level of the map with the 
correct keys.  Any 'new' keys can be left as is and not renamed.

The transformation was originally a threading macro, with a flatten and a
set/rename-keys, this has been improved to rename variables while looping
through each level of the map. The flatten however still accounts for ~80% of the time spent processing a record.

An example input would be as follows:

```
{:foo {:foo-host "host-1" :user {:foo-user "user-1" :foo-id "id-1"}}
 :bar {:bar-var "potato"}}
```

With an expected output of:

```
{:host "host-1" :user "user-1" :id "id-1" :var "potato"}
```

We've gone through and removed any java reflection, and type hinted the hottest
parts of our code so no more gains can be found there.  The last slow pieces
of code are as follows:

```
(def match-table {:foo-host :host
                  :foo-user :user
                  :foo-id :id
                  :bar-var :var})

(defn flatten-record
  "Take a nested record and recursively flatten."
  [^clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap record]
  (into {}
    (for [[k v] record]
      (if (map? v)
        (flatten-record v)
        ;; If the key's not found return itself as the default.
        {(get match-table k k) v}))))
```

The flatten-record function consumes the stack as it's lacking any tail call
optimisation, trampoline may be a better solution?  The records transformed are
a maximum of 5 deep, so there's no risk of a recursion overflow.

I'm mainly concerned about performance here, so am open to any hints!

Larger examples are available [here](https://gist.github.com/Poogles/4bce0b780354b536ae714fdc998b14e5).

Comment: I don't like type hinting `^clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`. For any map with more than 16 entries, this fails. `^clojure.lang.APersistentMap` might be better.

Comment: It's actually `^flatland.protobuf.PersistentProtocolBufferMap` in reality as it's protobuf we're deserialising.  I just grabbed that as an example.

Cheers for that though as I didn't know that behaviour.

Comment: You should post the real code and as complete as possible/necessary. The less you show us, the harder it gets to recommend any changes.

Comment: Not sure how this has been marked as off topic, the only change is I'm passing in a marginally different data structure.  The hot part of the code is still whats been presented.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try:

- You assemble a map at every level of nesting. It is probably quicker
  to pass up sequences of key/value pairs.
- Even the single entries return a map. We can cope with a
  `MapEntry` directly using `reduce` instead of `for`.

We might end up with ...

```
(defn flatten-record [record]
  (reduce
   (fn [a [k v]]
     (if (map? v)
       (into a (flatten-record v))
       (conj a (clojure.lang.MapEntry. (match-table k k) v))))
   []
   record))
```

I'm assuming it's quicker to build a `MapEntry` than a small vector or list.

The above returns a sequence. We have to convert the product into a map:

```
(def example-input {:foo {:foo-host "host-1" :user {:foo-user "user-1" :foo-id "id-1"}}
                    :bar {:bar-var "potato"}})

(into {} (flatten-record example-input))
;{:host "host-1", :user "user-1", :id "id-1", :var "potato"}
```

---

The recursive call of `flatten-record`is not in tail position, so neither `recur` nor `trampoline`are available.